# aws api gateway and lambda cors configuration HTTP api

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cors, aws-api-gateway

I have an aws lambda setup using nodejs to basically receive a request with query parameters, trigger another https request and then send the response back.
Configuration for this otherwise is essentially default.
I have then added a trigger to this lambda in the form of an api gateway HTTP api (not REST api).

I have managed to get the api itself to work however I am getting blocked with the usual CORS issues. (i verified the path with Moesif CORS and origin changer to make sure everything else works and it does).

My CORS configuration in the api gateway is basically set to have

```
 Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
 Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
 Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
 Access-Control-Expose-Headers: No Expose Headers are allowed
 Access-Control-Max-Age: 0 seconds
 Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: No
```

I keep finding different pages explaining how to enable cors and so on but mostly seem to be either for an old version of the configuration or for REST api's which look to be quite different.

As it stands, I get this error so i never am allowed to use my api:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://path.to.my.api?query1=a' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I would want to either allow all origins or disable CORS completely for this really.

Disclaimer: I am quite new to the whole aws infrastructure so some terminology related to it might still be not yet understood.

---

Edit 1:

After some more digging. I have realised that the call that is failing with the cors error is the first of the two calls happening.
That is to say, this is the call that is ending up on my google domain (which normally would redirect temporarily to my aws gateway - this was setup following instrctions on aws to make a "synthetic record" on the domain settings to return a 302 to the execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com url), not the call that returns the actual data.

---

Edit 2:

I have tried adding a route in my api gateway for OPTIONS on the same path, pointed to my lambda which returns the appropriate headers when triggered, however this doesn't seem to get called at all in this case. So i imagine api gateway is trying to handle it on its own but failing somehow

Comment: Are you returning cors headers from lambda response?

Comment: I am currently not. I had tried but removed them as the API gateway says that if cors is configured there it will ignore headers from my backend. And I believe they only need to be returned during an OPTIONS call not the actual call no?

Comment: Cors exception you are getting is for options method or from actual call? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-output-format

Comment: It seems to be during the actual call. I have tried adding  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*"  to all my return options inside the lambda, but  still get the same error.  The response headers seem to not contain my header however?

Comment: @nirvana124 added some more details in the actual ticket